# Enabling and accessing template method

Tags: c++, function, templates

In the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<type_traits>
using std::enable_if;
using std::is_same;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
struct S{
        S(){t = static_cast<T>(NULL);}
        template<typename U,typename enable_if<is_same<T,U>::value>::type>void operator()(U&& rrU){t = rrU;}

        T t;
};

int main(){

        S<int> s;
        return(0);
}
```

how could I instantiate and use the `operator()`template method defined within the template struct, after the instantiation of the template struct in `main()`?

Comment: You call it...?

Comment: `s(S<int>{});`?

Comment: Btw, t is better initialized in init-list rather than in ctor's body; and you might want to `forward` u in assignment.

Comment: @StoryTeller your attitude is quite disappointing...in addition to not being helpful, I could also see that you have knocked off 4 points from my credit...

Comment: I daresay my attitude is not as disappointing as yours. I suppose it's easier to blame others than to admitting the shortcomings of this post, innit?

Comment: @StoryTeller I have neither interest nor time to engage with you in a pointless debate on this matter. But I presume that this forum is also meant to provide help and guidance to developers who are not on top of the more nuanced concepts and their usage. I have tried to conform to the thumb rule of a MWE in my question. And if there is something lacking in my post or even erroneous, I would appreciate it if someone were to point it out to me, rather than talking in riddles.

Comment: That's where you are wrong, it's not a forum, it's a Q&A site. Nobody is here to guide you, it's up to you to ask a clear question. You can visit the [help] to improve upon your posting quality, I'm done pouring energy down this rat hole.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but the **type** will be **deduced** during compilation, thus you don't have to worry about that. Anyway, I would implement your example as follows (and it is based on my understanding of your intentions):

```
/** @file: test.cpp */
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S {
  S() : t(0)  { };

  template <typename U>
  void operator()(U &&rrU) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value, "typename U must be equal to typename T"); 
    t = rrU; 
  }

  T t;
};

int main() {
  S<int> s;

  int a = 10;
  s(std::move(a));
#ifdef RAISES_ERROR
  double b = 10.0;
  s(std::move(b));
#endif
  return (0);
}
```

This can be compiled in two ways:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

that compiles fine, and a second case that **raises a compilation error** (is that what you want?), but the error can be made self-explanatory:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -DRAISES_ERROR test.cpp

test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void S<T>::operator()(U&&) [with U = double; T = int]’:
test.cpp:26:17:   required from here
test.cpp:12:5: error: static assertion failed: Error
     static_assert(std::is_same<T,U>::value, "typename U must be equal to typename T");
     ^
```

Comment: @@Matteo Ragni Appreciate your thoughts. My intention was to explore the usage of std::enable_if() in the context mentioned.

Comment: Ah ok, then my answer is completely off-topic... BUT IMHO I don't think `enable_if` has some interesting use in your example. It is used mainly in case of SFINAE conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), that you do not have in that case.